# Async seems to be synchronous

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am not sure if I am missing something here but more for loop seems to be executing synchronously even though I await all tasks out side of it.

Here is my code below:

```java
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var t = Start();
}

public static async Task < List < Task < TaskInfo >>> Start() {
    var listOfTasks = new List < Task < TaskInfo >> ();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        var process = new Processor();
        listOfTasks.Add(process.Process(i));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
    return listOfTasks;
}
```

I pass in the taskId to log out just to see the order the tasks execute.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

EDIT:

Changed code to this based on the answers and comments below and it still appears synchronously:

```
    public class StartWork
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public Processor Processor { get;}

    public StartWork()
    {
        Processor = new Processor();
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = Start();
    }

    public static async Task<TaskInfo[]> Start()
    {
        var tasks = new List<StartWork>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var work = new StartWork
            {
                TaskId = i
            };
            tasks.Add(work);
        }

        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(i => i.Processor.Process(i.TaskId)));
    }
```

The function I am calling in processor class:

```
 public Task<TaskInfo> Process(int taskId)
    {
        try
        {
            taskId = taskId + 1;
            stopwatch.Start();
            using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(xxDev))
            {
                @event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

                var replyTo = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var messageQueue = bus.Advanced.QueueDeclare(replyTo, autoDelete: true);

                bus.Advanced.Consume(messageQueue, (payload, properties, info) =>
                {
                    ReceivePdf(payload, properties, info);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                });

                taskInfo.InputFile = inputFile;
                var html = File.ReadAllText(inputFile);
                taskInfo.Html = html;

                var message = PrepareMessage(new RenderRequest()
                {
                    Html = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html),
                    Options = new RenderRequestOptions()
                    {
                        PageSize = "A4",
                        ImageQuality = 70,
                        PageLoadRetryAttempts = 3
                    }
                });

                var correlation = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                Console.WriteLine($"CorrelationId: {correlation}, TaskId {taskId}");

                var props = new MessageProperties
                {
                    CorrelationId = correlation,
                    ReplyTo = replyTo,
                    Expiration = "6000"
                };

                Publish(bus, props, message);
                taskInfo.CorrelationId = Guid.Parse(correlation);
                @event.WaitOne();
                stopwatch.Stop();
                taskInfo.TimeTaken = stopwatch.Elapsed;
                return Task.FromResult(taskInfo);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskInfo.OutputFile = Empty;
            return Task.FromResult(taskInfo);
        }
    }

        void ReceivePdf(byte[] payload, MessageProperties properties, MessageReceivedInfo info)
    {
        var file = Format(outputFile, properties.CorrelationId);
        taskInfo.OutputFile = file;

        Console.WriteLine("Output written to " + file);

        File.WriteAllBytes(file, payload);

        var remaining = Interlocked.Decrement(ref outstandingRequests);

        if (remaining == 0)
        {
            @event.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The loop *is* synchronous. The tasks that the loop adds to the list are asynchronous.

Comment: You have to `await` the `Start` and make `Main` as `async`

Comment: Please explain why you think it is synchronous, what are you observing that seems to differ from what you expected (and of course, also explain what you expected to happen). Can you also show the code in `process.Process`? If that code is not asynchronous in nature, it doesn't matter what the code in your question does.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - In the console window it outputs the taskId in order for example 1,2,3,4,5,6 I would expect the order to be different a some point if it was running async?

Comment: Then you need to show us the code in the Process method. Please note that merely adorning a method with `async` will *not* introduced any threads by itself. The code is still very much synchronous until you call actual async code.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Added to the post

Comment: There is no async code in that Process method, and this is the reason. Everything is still synchronous, even though you added tasks and `async` keywords.

Comment: OK, that will explain it then. I think a different approach is required. That code was already there I am just trying to make it execute X amount of threads at a time

Comment: There seems to be 1 thing inside your Process method that could be considered async in nature, and it is the event you use, you could rewrite the `@event.WaitOne();` statement into one using a task and `await`. So there seems to be ways to refactor that method into being more async in nature, but it will require a rewrite.

Comment: @TheKeyboarder take all of the unnecessary `Task` stuff out of your `Process` method and make it synchronous, then just invoke it with `Task.Run` to schedule it on the threadpool. Then await your list.

Comment: You are not signalling `@event` though, is that your actual code? If so then my quick glance through it indicates it might be broken.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Added the function that signals the event (I believe) to the original post. I'll take a look at the comments above and refactor it

Comment: taskInfo where is declared?

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti its a private field within the class and initialised in the class constructor

Comment: Can you post the code, I guess there is a problem because you call Task.FromResult(taskInfo) that force it to run synchronously

Answer (score 1):

This is a synchronous task

```
listOfTasks.Add(process.Process(i));
```

You are just adding items to the list.

This is also a synchronous task

```
process.Process(i);
```

The task that the function above returns is asynchronous and it will execute asynchronously in the whenAll call of your code.

Bear in mind that when all will wait for all tasks to run and if the task is trivial, since they start one after the other, will most times run sequentially by chance.

You will see some difference if the task code executed differentiated in execution time based on input.

Comment: Don't paste it here. Edit your question. @TheKeyboarder

Answer (score 0):

First async doesn't mean multithread, async is used to run background task without blocking UI or to run I/O operations without bloking main thread.
Usually the operating system handles async with multithreading, but there is no guarantee.
If you want be sure to start multiple threads use Thread.Start.

Anyway in your code you force your code to run synchronously, because you call the async method start in the Main method without await.

You need to change the code to:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
   var t = await Start();
}
```

or without waiting to (but the program risk to terminate before the task complete):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Task.Run(async () => {
       var t = await Start();
   });
}
```

Comment: Actually, by not waiting for the task in Main, he risk the process terminating before all tasks have completed. It doesn't change the async nature of the code that is being called though. If that code was truly async, it would still be async regardless of how Main was structured. He *should* fix the code according to your suggestions, but that doesn't explain why the rest of his code is synchronous.